# Angular get custom track by in ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

We can track item by $index in ng-repeat and display their index like this

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  [{{$index}}] -- {{n}}
</div>
```

Angular allow us to use a custom function to track objects in ng-repeat as the exemple on the official website

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by myTrackingFunction(n)">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

But is there a way to get our custom index ? (for example if myTrackingFunction return "n+count" how can i diplay n+count ?)

i'd like to have something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by ($customIndex = myTrackingFunction(n))">
  [{{$customIndex}}] -- {{n}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` for this, but the recommended way would be to add a property to each of your array items and to track this property